# Mongoose how to see which mongodb query is being generated nothing returned from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using mongodb with mongoose.

When I connect to the database via the terminal and run the command:

```
db.locphoto.find({})
```

It successfully returns the list of items that I'm looking for.

Alternatively, on my application I do the following and unfortunately it constantly returns `[]`. I was hoping someone could show me the way to see which mongodb query is generated so that I'm able to check if it is correctly generating `db.locphoto.find({})`.

My controller code is as follows:

```js
var LocPhoto = require('../models/locPhoto');

module.exports.getGalleryPictures = function(req, res) {
  LocPhoto.find({}, function(err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

And my model code is as follows:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var locPhotoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  challengeId: String,
  image: String,
  main: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('LocPhoto', locPhotoSchema);
```

I'd really appreciate if someone knows how to see the command that is being generated so that I can check this better in the future, since I've had this issue a few times already, it's usually to do with capital letters etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're not properly creating the schema , you have to use new keyword

```
   var locPhotoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      challengeId: String,
      image: String,
      main: Number,
    });
```